# Many to many communication

Tags: microservices, zeromq, netmq

I have several servers handling the same requests and several clients sending requests. The servers are routers to keep/track the identity of the clients and the clients are dealers which round robin servers. Does this dealer/router pair without a broker make sense? It works and fits my need but I don't see this pattern on the official guides.

Comment: I can understand this "The client are dealers which are round robin servers", would you please explain more ?

Comment: Client1 calls server1 and server2 one by one. First it calls server1, then server2, then server1 and so on. So one client can call different servers, servers respond to the same client (current caller).

Comment: Are you trying to implement some approach of load balancing ?

Comment: Yes, something like Freelance pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to balance your request loads between servers at the client, yes you are right. This pattern is named client-side-load-balancing. You can read about that [here](https://medium.com/@dannystudio/client-side-v-s-server-side-load-balancing-67c154a2c535)

But I'm not sure about your implementation.

You can see more in google SRE [book](https://sre.google/sre-book/handling-overload/).

Comment: Yes, I have client side balancing but the question focuses on the type of zmq sockets. I am just not sure if router<->dealer is a good pair to go, without any req/rep etc.